# GWT+GXT serialization goes wrong after minor changes. But why?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I thought I knew GWT serialization rules, but apparently I don't. This case is just weird, I'm trying to figure it out for couple of hours, still no luck. Maybe you, guys, could lend me a hand on this one?

First things first: the stack trace.

```
...blah blah blah...
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'geos.dto.common.client.Market' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = null
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:619)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.HashSet_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(HashSet_CustomFieldSerializer.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.HashSet_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(HashSet_CustomFieldSerializer.java:51)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.HashSet_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(HashSet_CustomFieldSerializer.java:28)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:621)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:35)
    ... 78 more
```

So it appears the problem lies in `geos.dto.common.client.Market`. Let's see the minimal that still can be compiled.

```
package geos.dto.common.client;

public class Market extends RowModel<Integer>  {
    public static final String ID="id";
    public static final String NAME="name";

    public Market() { }
    public Market(int id, String name) { }
    public String getName() { }
    public void setName(String name) { }    
}
```

Either I **really** need a vacation, or it's just fine. **A LOT of DTO classes inherit from RowModel, they are working and are serialized properly, no problems there.** But of course I'll show you anyway. This time some GXT stuff ahead. This class is unedited, but still fairly simple.

```
package geos.dto.common.client;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModelData;

public class RowModel<I> extends BaseModelData implements IdentifiableModelData<I> {    
    private I identifier;
    private String identifierProperty;

    public RowModel() { }    

    public RowModel(String identifierProperty) {
        this.identifierProperty=identifierProperty;
    }       

    @Override
    public I getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(I identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        if((identifierProperty!=null)&&(!identifierProperty.isEmpty())) {
            set(identifierProperty,identifier);
        }
    }

    public void setIdentifierProperty(String identifierProperty) {
        this.identifierProperty = identifierProperty;
        if(identifier!=null) {
            set(identifierProperty,identifier);
        }
    }

    public String getIdentifierProperty() {
        return identifierProperty;
    }        

    @Override
    public <X> X set(String property, X value) {
        if(property.equals(identifierProperty)&&((identifier==null)||(!getIdentifier().equals(value)))) {
            setIdentifier((I)value);
        }
        return super.set(property, value);
    }            
}
```

Looks somewhat weird, I know, but these identifier is really important. I removed `toString()` which - in this case - returns null (because internal `RpcMap` is null, and it's null because no values are set in `Market` class). And the last piece of code, the interface implemented by `RowModel`:

```
package geos.dto.common.client;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.ModelData;
import java.io.Serializable;

public interface IdentifiableModelData<I> extends ModelData, Serializable {
    public I getIdentifier();
}
```

The versions are GWT 2.4.0 and GXT 2.2.5. I want to upgrade it soon, but first I want to deal with problems like this one.

And that would be all, I think. Do you see anything I can't see? I certainly hope so! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Expecting, that your package structure follows the naming conventions: Is it possible that you have to move your Market-class into the shared package?

If you make a rcp call, the class is serialized on the client side and deserialized on the server side. There fore the class have to be accessible from the client and the server. If you class lies in the client-package, the server can't access this class. Classes that are used on the client and server side are put in a package called shared.

So, all classes that are only needed in your client, should be inside a package called client. Classes, that are needed on the server and the client side should be inside the shared package and classes, that are only neede on the server side are inside the server package.

This is my abstract class, that extends BaseModelData and lies inside the shared package:

```
package de.gishmo.leela.application.shared.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModelData;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class MyBaseModel
  extends BaseModelData
  implements Serializable {

  public final static String MYFIELD = "myField";

  public abstract String getModelName();

}
```

works well in RCP-calls.

And please implement the Serializable Interface.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by that, sorry! Could you please explain what shared package are you talking about?

Comment: Thank for the explanation! I definitely must refresh my GWT knowledge (I've started using it in 2008 and, to be honest, haven't read much of its documentation since then ;-) ). Anyway, server has the access to that class. In the meantime I've had an oblivion and got what is wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19661296/545834

Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I've got an oblivion.

The problem wasn't in that class, not at all. Thing is, it's transferred using another class, that extends RowModel as well. And it's set this way:

```
public void setMarkets(Set<Market> markets) {
    set(MARKETS,markets);
}
```

And because I haven't included the Market type in that class, GWT didn't know it should be serialized at compilation time. Adding `private Market _market;` in that class did the trick. Actually it's well known issue related to subclasses of `BaseModelData` (that it can't serialize types that are not declared as class fields), but I totally forgotten it...